# NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate memory leak

Tags: objective-c, core-data, memory-leaks, nsarray

I am get a huge memory leak when trying to use `NSPredicate` in a for-loop to search for records in a `NSArray` that has a `NSDate` field value within a date range - like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<nLen;i++)
{
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >=  %@ AND date <=  %@", dateStart,dateEnd];
  NSArray *result = [myDataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
```

Simple testing suggests that it is the `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` function that is leaking.

Using XCode Version 9.2 (9C40b) and iOS 11.2.1 on a iPhone 7s.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Is the leaked memory freed after the loop? Which objects are leaked?

Comment: It is freed after the method returns - not after the for-loop ends. But ARC does not release the NSArray with each iteration of the loop, as I would have expected. So with 15 000 iteration, over 1.2 GB of memory accumulated.

Comment: Actually in the end I switched to pre-sorting the data and then using C malloc techniques. No ARC mysteries and a speed increase of the order of 2 - from 60 secs to 0.6 secs.

Comment: `predicateWithFormat` and `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` return autoreleased objects, they are released when the autorelease pool is drained. Put an [@autoreleasepool block](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047) inside the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Willeke's response is the answer : Put an `@autoreleasepool` block inside the loop. Thanks!